# How could I access the data of this dict from a django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a dict with entries such as this:

```
d[(1,2,3)] = True
d[(4,5,6)] = False
```

How could I access them from the django template?

Comment: How are you going to use this dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I wrote a custom tag, because it feels too weird, and it's probably much slower to do the comparison in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing the dictionary by a tuple in the template is not possible, but for your particular case, you can do this:

```
{% for key,value in dictionary.items %}
    {% if key.0 == 1 and key.1 == 2 and key.2 == 3 %}
        {{ value }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```